# python closure type error in dict

Tags: python

I am trying to get some count values out of some algos I am using.

Here is a toy example:

```
def Count():
    a = dict(sys=0,dia=0,hr1=0,ox=0,hr2=0,wht=0)
    itr = [0]
    def C(a=a,itr=itr):
        '''closure to sum to a
        '''
        def b( cnt ):
            for k in a:
                #a[k] = a.get(k,None) + cnt.get(k,None) 
                a[k] = a.get(k,0) + cnt.get(k,0)       

            itr.append(1)
            print 'a ', a
            return a
        return b
    c=C()
    return c
    def get():
        return a;

fc=Count()
def toyalgo(fc):
    vitals = ['sys', 'dia', 'hr1', 'ox', 'hr2', 'wht']
    cc = np.random.randint(0,20,size=6)
    cnt = dict(izip( vitals, cc) )
    print 'new count ',cnt
    fc(cnt)
print 'fc'
toyalgo(fc)
toyalgo(fc)
```

with output looking like this with mutiple(+8) calls:

```
new count  {'wht': 1, 'hr1': 8, 'dia': 18, 'hr2': 13, 'sys': 17, 'ox': 5}
a  {'sys': 17, 'wht': 1, 'ox': 5, 'hr1': 8, 'dia': 18, 'hr2': 13}
new count  {'wht': 2, 'hr1': 12, 'dia': 12, 'hr2': 19, 'sys': 13, 'ox': 1}
a  {'sys': 30, 'wht': 3, 'ox': 6, 'hr1': 20, 'dia': 30, 'hr2': 32}
```

Unfortunately, when run on the real data set, cannot get past 5 calls without an

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

I thought this was due to a missing value, so tried to just change from `None` to `0`, but no luck.

Any help is great!

-- `get()` is just to get the closure variable a, ie the counts. (its untested not sure maybe `def get(a=a): return a` is the right way to do that...)

-- no luck with return fc(cnt); altough I did see that being the solution to another problem on SO with the same TypeError.

---edit --- 
great comments!
debugging using `not isinstance()` detected the error.  A list was being passed!

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` instead (after importing `numpy as np` and `from itertools import izip`).

Comment: You ned to show us the real code, plus the full traceback. Somewhere you are adding a list to an integer, which your code here simply doesn't do.

Comment: What is the dangling `def get()` supposed to do in here?

Comment: the code seems to run if you  `return fc(cnt)` in `toyalgo`

Comment: @MartijnPieters! Thankyou for the great comments! helped me to figure out the probem, you were correct, a list was being passed in real code!